# laravel queue disable database logging for failed jobs

Tags: laravel, redis, queue, laravel-9

Is there a way to disable the database logging of laravel when a job failed?

For example I'm just trying to write a log message, which would enough for this specific job:

job.php

```
public function handle()
{
        //making an API request to an external API, storing some data inside cache
}

public function failed(Throwable $exception)
{
    Log::info("external API update failed");
}
```

I already tried to edit the `config/queue.php` file by:

```
'failed' => [
    'driver' => env('QUEUE_FAILED_DRIVER', 'database-uuids'),
    'database' => null,
    'table' => null,
],
```

This doesn't work, any idea how to get the database logging of failed jobs disabled?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have to set `config/queue.php` to the following:

```
'failed' => [
    'driver' => null
    'database' => null,
    'table' => null,
],
```

You should be able to find clues within the `laravel/framework` folder within the vendor folder in your project, e.g.
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/DatabaseFailedJobProvider.php.

The saving to database is done in the `DatabaseFailedJobProvider` class, the `log` function specifically.

Based on the `QueueServiceProvider`'s `registerFailedJobServices` function, you would need to set the driver to `null` or the 'null' string in order to get it to run the `NullFailedJobProvider`, where the log function is empty.